Will Google Scholar update the title of existing papers?
I have published a journal paper with IEEE; however, I noticed that both the journal paper and its conference version have the exact same title, which may cause confusion. I contacted IEEE to request a slight modification to the journal paper title, and it has since been successfully updated on IEEE Xplore. This happened in May 2024.
However, Google Scholar has not yet reflected this update. I have reached out to Google Scholar support regarding this issue but have not received a response so far. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or advice on how to resolve this.

sorry, what google is doing is unfortunately a mystery.

Even the time to initial indexing of a paper is quite variable.

You can edit the paper name on Google Scholar. I've edited other information before when they refused to get the correct information or preferred to show the pre-release version information, not the conference one.
Clicking on the paper opens the paper information. Afterwards, click on edit in the top left corner.

Thank you for the suggestions. A few months ago, I attempted to manually correct the journal paper title in my Google Scholar profile. However, the updated journal paper still does not appear correctly linked to my profile—it only shows with a '*' symbol above it.
Additionally, after making this adjustment, the conference paper in my profile no longer links to any papers. I would appreciate any further advice on how to resolve these issues and ensure both papers are correctly linked in my Google Scholar profile.

@CharlieNie, I would assume you have to unmerge the journal and conference papers and change the name of the conference paper. Then, it will keep them separate and with the correct citation count. Usually, the * symbol means GS is adding up the citation count from two references. If that is the case, you should see the two entries and select the one you want to unmerge when clicking on edit.
